# Getting XAER_RMERR error in IBM web sphere

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, websphere, oracle12c

We are getting the below error when we run the services in IBM WebSphere server.
Can you please tell me why we are getting the below error.

```
[10/5/16 5:58:28:812 UTC] 00000007 XARecoveryDat A   WTRN0146I: Obtained 0 xid(s) from xa recover on XAResource: XYZ of which 0 will be processed by this server
[10/5/16 5:58:28:814 UTC] 00000007 XARecoveryDat A   WTRN0151I: Preparing to call xa recover on XAResource: ABC
[10/5/16 5:58:28:872 UTC] 00000007 WSRdbXaResour E   DSRA0304E:  XAException occurred. XAException contents and details are: "".
[10/5/16 5:58:28:872 UTC] 00000007 WSRdbXaResour E   DSRA0302E:  XAException occurred.  Error code is: XAER_RMERR (-3).  Exception is: <null>
[10/5/16 5:58:28:872 UTC] 00000007 XARminst      E   WTRN0037W: The transaction service encountered an error on an xa_recover operation. The resource was com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl@4966bf0a. The error code was XAER_RMERR. The exception stack trace follows: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:730)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl.recover(WSRdbXaResourceImpl.java:1105)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.XARminst.recover(XARminst.java:141)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.XARecoveryData.recover(XARecoveryData.java:716)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.PartnerLogTable.recover(PartnerLogTable.java:432)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.resync(RecoveryManager.java:1542)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.performResync(RecoveryManager.java:2275)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RecoveryManager.performResync(RecoveryManager.java:119)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.run(RecoveryManager.java:2228)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Answer (score 2):

XA is the Oracle implementation for processing distributed transactions using two-phase commit. The above error indicate that WAS is trying to call an XA Recover operation on your data source, which has been defined as an XA-type data source. The call fails, likely because the database is not enabled to support an external transaction manager (WAS, in this case).

If you don't need to use XA transactions, you can remove the transaction logs from WAS to get rid of the error ([profile_root]/tranlog folder). If you need XA support for your applications, then you can enable it on the Oracle side using the `initxa.sql` script that is shipped with the Oracle DB.

Answer (score 1):

**Error description:**

When using message-driven beans (MDBs) with the WebSphere MQ
Java Message Service (JMS) provider in WebSphere Application
Server v7, an XAER_RMERR error can occur if the connection is
broken while a message is being delivered to the MDB.

**Local fix:**

Pause and restart the affected endpoint by following
the below steps:
1.Open the WebSphere administration console

2 Open the enterprise application page

3.Click on the application

4.Click on the Runtime tab

5.Manage message endpoints link

6.Select the failing endpoint and click pause

7.Repeat steps 1-6 then select resume